# High number of requests with LazyLoad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest, slick.js

I have a web page which has a lot of images on it. The majority of these images are within a slider, using SlickSlider.js with Lazyload.

The page has a load time of 3.87s seconds but has over 134 requests being made. Looking at the requests, they all seem to be the images i have in the slider.

Is it normal for a request to be made even though they haven't been loaded? As soon as i click the arrow on the slider it loads into the DOM again?

Link to site:
http://bluemoontesting.co.uk/susatchwell/projects/restoration-modernisation-classic-cotswold-manor-house/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the attribute data-lazy="your-image-url" inside all your image tags and leave off the src.

I saw you're also using the srcset attribute, so you have to read [this](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/pull/1661) too if you don't want several http requests.

Comment: Hi Gabriel,

Thanks for getting back to me. In my source code i do have data-lazy="" inside all the images tags for the slider but on the actual webpage it says src="". Is this because of the srcset attribute on it?

Comment: The srcset also makes a http request, so you have to do the workaround that is on the link i passed for you.

Comment: Okay cheers mate, i'll have a read and let you know how i get on.